# do provided cell editors work with ag-grid-vue3?

Tags: ag-grid-vue

I am using ag-grid via ag-grid-vue3,  and when I try applying one of the cell editors such as agDateStringCellEditor, it doesn't seem to have any effect. For example, with this column definition:

```
     {
    headerName: 'End Date',
    field: 'endDate',
    sortable: true,
    resizable: true,
    flex: 2,
    editable: true,
      cellEditor: 'agDateStringCellEditor'
  }
```

Here are what the imports at the top of the module look like:

```
import 'ag-grid-community/styles//ag-grid.css'
import 'ag-grid-community/styles//ag-theme-alpine.css'
import {onMounted, ref, watch} from 'vue'
import type { Ref } from 'vue'
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue3'
```

And here's the template:

```
<template>
  <ag-grid-vue
    class="ag-theme-alpine caas-ac__pinned-grid"
    :columnDefs="columnDefs"
    :rowData="rowData"
    :pagination="false"
    :getRowStyle="getRowStyle"
    :pinnedTopRowData="pinnedTopRowData"
    @cell-editing-stopped="onCellEditingStopped"
    :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
    @grid-ready="onGridReady"
    :single-click-edit="true"
    :stop-editing-when-cells-lose-focus="true"
  >
  </ag-grid-vue>
</template>
```

The editor for the endDate cell looks like a regular text input. I tried it with agCheckboxCellEditor as well. Same result.

Answer (score 1):

Provided cell editors work with ag-grid-vue3

[image: ag-grid-vue3]

Here's the code

```
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-grid.css';
import 'ag-grid-community/styles/ag-theme-alpine.css';
import { AgGridVue } from 'ag-grid-vue3';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

const VueExample = {
  template: `
    <div style="height: 100%">
      <ag-grid-vue
        style="width: 100%; height: 100%;"
        class="ag-theme-alpine"
        :columnDefs="columnDefs"
        :rowData="rowData"
        :defaultColDef="defaultColDef"
        @grid-ready="onGridReady"
      >
      </ag-grid-vue>
    </div>
    `,
  components: {
    'ag-grid-vue': AgGridVue,
  },
  data: function () {
    return {
      columnDefs: [
        {
          headerName: 'Number',
          field: 'id',
          cellEditor: 'agNumberCellEditor',
          cellEditorParams: { precision: 0 },
        },
        {
          headerName: 'End Date',
          field: 'date',
          sortable: true,
          resizable: true,
          flex: 2,
          editable: true,
          cellEditor: 'agDateStringCellEditor',
        },
      ],
      gridApi: null,
      columnApi: null,
      defaultColDef: {
        flex: 1,
        resizable: true,
        editable: true,
      },
      rowData: null,
    };
  },
  created() {
    this.rowData = data;
  },
  methods: {
    onGridReady(params) {
      this.gridApi = params.api;
      this.gridColumnApi = params.columnApi;
    },
  },
};

const data = Array.from(Array(20).keys()).map((val, index) => ({
  id: index,
  date: `2023-06-${index < 9 ? '0' + (index + 1) : index + 1}`,
}));

createApp(VueExample).mount('#app');
```

I have optimized your code in this plunker: https://plnkr.co/plunk/Ea4F5dfKBKhdlISQ